# Javascript JSON names are unique IDs

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to extract the "id" and "name" from a JSON object, but the objects name is a GUID.  How do I get these values?

```
var object = {
  "vehicles": {
    "c73c0ac8-4edf-409e-84b0-92bf9bd1c0aa": {
        "id": "c73c0ac8-4edf-409e-84b0-92bf9bd1c0aa",
        "name": "Van 1"
    },
    "32a57cda-42a9-4855-a340-4fe6cacaefa1": {
        "id": "32a57cda-42a9-4855-a340-4fe6cacaefa1",
        "name": "Van 2"
    },
    "1daf1f53-80b6-49d6-847a-0ee8b814e784": {
        "id": "1daf1f53-80b6-49d6-847a-0ee8b814e784",
        "name": "Van 3"
    }
  }
};

console.log(object.vehicle.????);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a `GUID` type in JavaScript. These are simply strings. try `Object.keys(object.vehicles);`

Comment: You have to either know the key or loop through the object .

Answer (score 1):

use this

```js
var object = {
  "vehicles": {
    "c73c0ac8-4edf-409e-84b0-92bf9bd1c0aa": {
      "id": "c73c0ac8-4edf-409e-84b0-92bf9bd1c0aa",
      "name": "Van 1"
    },
    "32a57cda-42a9-4855-a340-4fe6cacaefa1": {
      "id": "32a57cda-42a9-4855-a340-4fe6cacaefa1",
      "name": "Van 2"
    },
    "1daf1f53-80b6-49d6-847a-0ee8b814e784": {
      "id": "1daf1f53-80b6-49d6-847a-0ee8b814e784",
      "name": "Van 3"
    }
  }
};
console.log(
  Object.values(object.vehicles)
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I needed.